# beamer with tcolorbox: enumerate gives a compilation error

Tags: beamer, enumerate, tcolorbox, enumitem

For my poster, I use the `beamer` class with the `tcolorbox` package.

My problem is that using the `enumerate` environment gives the following compilation error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@enum@ ...fix item}##1}}}}}\beamer@cramped 
                                                  \raggedright \beamer@first...
l.18   }
```

which appears even with the following very simple MWE (the above error was actually produced with it, although the error message is similar for my document):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}

  \posterbox[]
  {name=part1}{%
    This is a test:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Just
    \item a
    \item test.
    \end{enumerate}
  }

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

The error apparently comes from the `enumerate` environment because the error disappears when I comment it in my document.

I couldn't find anything that explains the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the redefinition of `enumerate` done by `beamer`. The following for example works (but is just a fix, not a real solution in my eyes):

```
\let\enumeratebak\enumerate
\let\endenumeratebak\endenumerate
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}

  \posterbox[]
  {name=part1}{%
    This is a test:
    \begin{enumeratebak}
    \item Just
    \item a
    \item test.
    \end{enumeratebak}
  }

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Another (real) solution to your problem is adding the missing `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbposter}

  \posterbox[]
  {name=part1}{%
    This is a test:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Just
    \item a
    \item test.
    \end{enumerate}
  }

\end{tcbposter}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

** EDIT ** (have a look at the comments to the present answer):

There were actually two problems in my document. The first one was the absence of the `frame` environment, as was pointed out by **Skillmon** above. The second one was the presence of `\usepackage{enumitem}` in my preamble. This apparently causes another error when using an `enumerate` environment in such a document.

CONCLUSION: When using the `beamer` class in conjunction with the `tcolorbox` package, `enumerate` will work only if put inside a `frame` as described above and **without** using the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed it works for the MWE, but in my document I still get an error (not the same though): `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\labelenumi ->{
               \labelenumi }
`. This error only occurs when I uncomment the `enumerate` after having put into a `frame` everything that is inside the `document`.

Comment: @Giuseppe please try to build a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) which shows your problem and update your question.

Comment: @ Skillmon I started to create such a MWE, and while doing so I found the other problem. As you provided an important part of the solution, I directly edited your answer with what I found, and I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Giuseppe You'll wonder how often the error is found while creating a MWE. If you edit my answer, edit your question, too, because unedited my answer is correct for your unedited question.

Comment: @ Skillmon I edited your answer not because it is not correct, but because I wanted to add the other part of the solution to my problem. If I edit my question (by adding the `enumitem` package), your answer will become incorrect, because it only tackles one of the two problems I had. I think my question and your answer are good without modification because they allow to identify one problem separately from the other...

Comment: @Giuseppe if you edited both the answer and question all would be fine. But it's not that important. You might accept the answer then:)